# i'm trying to use image slide show cocoapods ,page indicator not work right only on my project but it works fine in demo and new projects

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

i'm trying to use imageSlideShow cocoapods i install it and try the demo and work fine , also used it in test project and works fine , but when i used it in my project page indicator not work and i try every thing but also not working and i create a new view controller in my project and make it init and run also not work 
this is my code

```
import UIKit
import ImageSlideshow
class test: UIViewController {

open override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .portrait
}

@IBOutlet var slideshow: ImageSlideshow!

let localSource = [ImageSource(imageString: "imageLoading")!,ImageSource(imageString: "imageLoading")!,ImageSource(imageString: "logo")!]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    slideshow.slideshowInterval = 5.0
    slideshow.pageIndicatorPosition = .init(horizontal: .center, vertical: .customUnder(padding: 50))
    slideshow.contentScaleMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill

    let pageControl = UIPageControl()
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black
    slideshow.pageIndicator = pageControl

    // optional way to show activity indicator during image load (skipping the line will show no activity indicator)
    slideshow.activityIndicator = DefaultActivityIndicator()
    slideshow.currentPageChanged = { page in
        print("current page:", page)
    }

    // can be used with other sample sources as `afNetworkingSource`, `alamofireSource` or `sdWebImageSource` or `kingfisherSource`
    slideshow.setImageInputs(localSource)

    let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(test.didTap))
    slideshow.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
}


    // guard let im = imageUrlString else {return "hello "}
    let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(test.didTap))
    slideshow.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)*/
}
@objc func didTap() {
    let fullScreenController = slideshow.presentFullScreenController(from: self)
    // set the activity indicator for full screen controller (skipping the line will show no activity indicator)
    fullScreenController.slideshow.activityIndicator = DefaultActivityIndicator(style: .white, color: nil)
}

}
```

and the result of that code make slide show but indicator not work it appear but not stretched and swapping correctly and as i marked in picture just color change and image but not clear number of image or any thing 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z2pQ0HFUQC0F0oyajo9gRHOLcqsU4_sJ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Looks like UIPageControl frame not set. If you remove all about pageControl - it will automatically place controls. Or you can create your own in storyboard:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageSlideshow: ImageSlideshow!
@IBOutlet weak var slideshowPageControl: UIPageControl!

var slideshowInputs: [InputSource] {
    let place = categoryPlaces[selectedIndex]
    return [
        ... your inputs
    ]
}

func setupData(){
    imageSlideshow.setImageInputs(slideshowInputs)
    slideshowPageControl.numberOfPages = slideshowInputs.count
    imageSlideshow.currentPageChanged = { page in
        self.slideshowPageControl.currentPage = page
    }
}
```

Comment: aslo i need to tell you , i think no problem in code , if you create a new project and add this code on your device or my device it will work correctly by i don't know the reason of damaging in page indicator in this project only :( but when i try to test in new project it works fine

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16RI6bIinDEFbJqqld_m0wUzki0BijFNK/view?usp=sharing) i think the problem in page indicator

Answer (score 0):

photoList is yours photos Model list,

```
    import ImageSlideshow
    
    .....
    
    @IBOutlet weak var slideshowPageControl: UIPageControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var slideShow: ImageSlideshow!
    
    .....
    
    
   func initslideShow()
                {
                    var photos = [KingfisherSource]()
                    for item photoList {
                        photos.append(KingfisherSource(urlString: item.photoUrl)!)
                    }
                    slideShow.setImageInputs(photos)
                    
                    let pageIndicator = UIPageControl()
                    pageIndicator.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = StyleManager.colors.colorPrimary
                    pageIndicator.pageIndicatorTintColor = StyleManager.colors.lightGray
                    slideShow.pageIndicator = pageIndicator
                    slideShow.activityIndicator = DefaultActivityIndicator(style: .white, color: nil)
                    
                    let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTap))
                    slideShow.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
                    
                    slideShow.zoomEnabled = true
                    
                    slideShow.contentScaleMode = .scaleAspectFill
                    slideShow.pageIndicatorPosition = PageIndicatorPosition(horizontal: .left(padding: 20), vertical: .bottom)
                    
                    slideshowPageControl.numberOfPages = photoList.count
                    slideShow.currentPageChanged = { page in
                        self.slideshowPageControl.currentPage = page
                    }
                }
                
  @objc func didTap() {
                    slideShow.presentFullScreenController(from: self)
                }
```